# How to provide a larger database with the App

Tags: iphone, database

I just had a chat with a member of the App review team and I was told, that providing a DB 10 MB is far to large for an app to be approved. The lady told me, that the issue with my app is that I am not compliant with guideline 2.23 of the storage guidelines. 
They, at least the person I talked to on the phone, claimed, that it an app copying a database on first launch of 10 MB will not be approved by Apple. 
I am copying my Database which contains a set of > 50'000 records from the resource folder into the Library folder. I am segregating the databases into 2 DBs, one DB, the user is actually applying the changes, and another DB, where the user can copy data from.

Question: Is there another way instead of copying a DB from the resource dir? I decided the resource-folder to library-folder approach, as this is simply the fastest and seemed to me the most user-friendly approach. Of course I can make the user download the DBs from the internet. But this is yet another process step, which I personally would not like to undertake as an end-user.

I still don't have any specs from Apple, what the maximum allowed size of a first time launch DB is. Don't know, why Apple makes such a fuzz about this information.

Anyway, I would really appreciate your comments and possible solution approaches.

René

Comment: Are you sure the issue is only that the file size is too large? I've never had an issue with file size, except when the file is too large for iCloud backups. Unless some new requirement has come about in the past couple weeks, it should be enough to make sure the file is in an appropriate "Private Documents" folder and marked with the "Skip Backup" extended attribute. ie, http://ios-dev-blog.com/how-to-add-skip-backup-on-icloud-attribute-to-file/  Apple's docs on file storage are spelled out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for your respone VeryVito. I have talked to the technical support from Apple and they told me too, that I should be fine, if I segregate static from the dynamic data and flag the static as non-backup. I understand that statement and that is exactly what I implemented in the revised release (not yet submitted). The lady on the phone today, however, told me that it is not ok to initially propagate a DB with 10 MB. "No way that gets approved", that were her exact words. I also think that she did not know what she was talking about, but I have to be sure, before submitting my app again.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if that were really Apple's stance, and I'd guess she was referring to "backupable" data, if anything. Although apps over 20MB cannot be downloaded over 3G, I think the official app size limit is way larger (2GB when last checked), and I'm not aware of any more granular file breakdown requirements. Unfortunately, this is just based on my experience, but for what it's worth, I can personally attest that an app with an 11+ MB database was approved as recently as late March.

Comment: VeryVito, yes that what she was referring to. She also mentioned to check the setting in iCloud like this: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage 
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps" 
- Check your app's storage
And this has only to do with the backup size, not the size of the DB actually provided with the bundle. Right? That's why I think, she did not really understand, that I resolved the issue with the revides release.

Comment: That sounds right to me. Good luck with the revised version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may mention here, that my solution to the issue was, not copying the static database at all. I simply leave it in the bundle and read the data from there. As it is read-only data the app is fine like this. And Apple was happy. Got it approved after that change. Thanks to all for the support. 
René

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The correct approach to take here is to move the file to Library/Caches folder. That folder is cleaned up when there is low memory situation and also never backed up to iCloud. I have an app which has 36 MB of database file. But I dont bundle it with the app. When the app is opened for the first time The app tells the user to download the DB once. This way the app size is drastically reduced.

Any specific reason why you are bundling the db with the app?

Comment: Thanks Vashishta. That is an approach I have thought of too. I prefer bundling the DB as it simply is the more user-friendly approach. Usability is for me more important that a few MB. And I have flagged the directory I am storing the larger DB as non-backup.

Comment: Makes sense. In my case the DB has to be updated every 4 months. So I took that approach.